# Weird sleep behaviour inside signal handler

Tags: c, unix, signals, kill

Hope you are doing well

I want to write a program in C that loops infinitly and prints pid and ppid every 3 seconds without using any predefined loop (no for no while ..)

The problem is that when i use sleep system call inside the signal handler it doesn't print anything but when i comment it loops infintly  and prints what i want.

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

void handle1(int signum){
    //sleep(3); // when i remove the sleep it loop infinitly and prints 
    printf("pid=%d ppid=%d",getpid(),getppid());
    if(signum==SIGUSR1){
        kill(getpid(),SIGUSR1);
    }
}
int main(int argc , char* argv[]){    
    signal(SIGUSR1,handle1);
    kill(getpid(),SIGUSR1);
}
```

Comment: *Only* async-signal-safe functions may be safely called from a signal handler.  Neither `sleep()` nor `printf()` are async-signal-safe.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04

Comment: I think there is no way i cant use a loop after all . So the problem is in the approach that i used.

Comment: The table that @AndrewHenle links to shows that `sleep()` is async-signal safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard pretty much only allows you to do one thing in a signal handler that affects global state. Set a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable. Calling `printf`, `sleep` and such in a signal handler is not allowed.

Lots of programs break those rules so systems make other things work and you're probably lucky and your printf happens to work (there are situations where it definitely won't), but I can think of many systems where `sleep` has no chance of ever working.

Basically, you're breaking the rules so much that if this happens to work on some system it will only be because of luck. Not because it's a correct program.

Comment: `sleep` is documented to be signal-async-safe. Of course, care needs to be taken, but such is code requiring precision.