# How to make libreadline or libedit cope with SIGALRM?

Tags: c, linux, signals, libreadline, editline

I am writing a Linux program that interacts with some custom hardware
via GPIO lines. It uses a timer periodically delivering `SIGALRM` in
order to manage the timing of these interactions, and there is quite
some work performed within the signal handler. The program offers a
command-line interface, and I would love to have the line-editing
convenience provided by [libreadline](https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). Unfortunately, it would seem
libreadline does not cope well with those periodic signals. I also tried
the readline compatibility mode of [libedit](https://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/) (a.k.a. “editline”), with
no luck.

Is there an easy way to have readline capability in a program that
receives numerous `SIGALRM` signals?

### Symptoms

When using libreadline, if the timer is running, some of the characters
typed are randomly echoed twice. For example, typing "help" may result
in "heelp" being displayed on the terminal. The issue is only apparent
in the echo: the program does receive the word as typed (i.e. "help").

When using libedit in readline compatibility mode, if the timer is
running, `readline()` returns `NULL` whenever it is interrupted by the
`SIGALRM` signal.

When the timer is stopped, everything works as expected, both with
libreadline and with libedit.

### Environment

Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest apt packages libreadline-dev (version
8.0-4) and libedit-dev (3.1-20191231-1). The program will eventually be
deployed on a Raspberry Pi running Raspberry Pi OS.

### Example code

Here is an attempt at a minimal(ish), reproducible example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#ifdef USE_LIBEDIT
# include <editline/readline.h>
#else
# include <readline/readline.h>
#endif

#define PERIOD_US  1000  // 1.0 ms
#define DELAY_NS 700000  // 0.7 ms

/* Timer settings. */
const struct itimerval interval_off = {
    .it_value    = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = 0 },
    .it_interval = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = 0 }
};
const struct itimerval interval_1ms = {
    .it_value    = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = PERIOD_US },
    .it_interval = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = PERIOD_US }
};

static void sigalrm_callback(int signum)
{
    (void) signum;

    // Simulate work by busy-wating for DELAY_NS.
    struct timespec end, now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    end.tv_nsec += DELAY_NS;
    end.tv_sec  += end.tv_nsec / 1000000000;
    end.tv_nsec %= 1000000000;
    do
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
    while (now.tv_sec < end.tv_sec
            || (now.tv_sec == end.tv_sec && now.tv_nsec < end.tv_nsec));
}

static int should_quit = 0;

/* Interpret and free line. */
void interpret(char *line)
{
    if (!line) {
        printf("Got NULL line\n");
    } else if (line[0] == '\0') {
        /* Ignore empty line. */
    } else if (strcmp(line, "help") == 0) {
        puts("help    print this help\n"
             "start   start the interval timer at 1 kHz\n"
             "stop    stop the interval timer\n"
             "quit    end the program");
    } else if (strcmp(line, "start") == 0) {
        setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &interval_1ms, NULL);
        printf("Periodic timer started.\n");
    } else if (strcmp(line, "stop") == 0) {
        setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &interval_off, NULL);
        printf("Periodic timer stopped.\n");
    } else if (strcmp(line, "quit") == 0) {
        should_quit = 1;
    } else {
        printf("Unknown command \"%s\".\n", line);
    }
    free(line);
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Catch SIGALRM. */
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_handler = sigalrm_callback;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, NULL);

    /* Process commands. */
    while (!should_quit) {
        char *line = readline("> ");
        interpret(line);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile either with

```sh
gcc -O2 readline-alrm.c -lreadline -o readline-alrm
```

or

```sh
gcc -O2 -DUSE_LIBEDIT readline-alrm.c -ledit -o readline-alrm
```

**Edit**: I moved the command interpreter out of `main()`.

Comment: Doing much in a signal handler, especially I/O,  is asking for trouble. Better would be to set a flag and return.  Wait on the flag in the regular code. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/41613943/1216776

Comment: @stark: 1. That signal handler work happens essentially inside a library that I did not write, is too complex to rewrite, and has proved to be reliable. 2. The “work” is mostly GPIO. Nothing that interferes with the state of MT-Unsafe functions.

Comment: Why do you need an alarm?

Comment: @wildplasser: In order to handle interactions with the hardware at very specific times.

Comment: Create a queueing-mechanism, and busy wait in the main code. Let the sighandler just set a (volatile) flag. If you don't want to block in readline() things will get more complex.

Comment: @wildplasser: I do not want to change the (quite complex) library that does this signal handling.

Comment: You are simply not "allowed" to use non reentrant functions in signal handlers. Doing calls to most IO functions is a no go. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Comment: @Klaus: This is not the issue: `clock_gettime()` is async-signal-safe. C.f. signal-safety(7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. The issue can be fixed by using the asynchronous
“alternate” interface of readline. In the example program from the
question, replace `main()` with this:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* Catch SIGALRM. */
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_handler = sigalrm_callback;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, NULL);

    /* Process commands. */
    rl_callback_handler_install("> ", interpret);
    while (!should_quit) {
        fd_set fds;
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
        int ret = select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
#ifdef FIX_BUG
        /* Restart on interrupted system call. */
        if (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR)
                continue;
#endif
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds))
            rl_callback_read_char();
    }
    putchar('\n');
    rl_callback_handler_remove();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that the issue is fixed only if the macro `FIX_BUG` is defined.

Here is my understanding of the problem. When `select()` is interrupted
by a signal, it returns `-1` with `errno` set to `EINTR`. When this
happens, most of the time the file descriptor set `fds` turns out empty.
In some cases, however, `select()` leaves `STDIN_FILENO` within `fds`.
In this case, the program should *not* attempt to process its input. If
we call `rl_callback_read_char()` despite `select()` having returned
`-1`, then we have the double-echo issue.

I wonder whether this is a bug in the implementation of `readline()`.
Maybe it is implemented on top of this async interface and it fails to
check the value returned by `select()`?